# The contextual meaning of "would" in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, subjunctives

What is the meaning of **'would'** in the following sentence?

> It's not what we **would** have expected from a professional service.

Answer (score 0):

In a conditional sense, but not fully said:

> 1. It's not what we would have expected from a professional service <s>If I had requested it.</s>
> 2. It's not what we would have expected from a professional service <s>If I requested it.</s>

You can introduce the conditional clause regarding the context.

Comment: Could you tell me why you have crossed the sentence if i had requested,had requested.
 I'm also confused, In one place there is had requested and requested in another place, why ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma Because I used a mixed conditional. They are struckout because are implicitly mentioned to form the conditional construction.

Comment: I'm afraid to say  I'm not understanding what you're saying

Comment: @yubrajsharma The "if I had..." part is left unsaid. You don't need to say it, but it's understood as completing the conditional. Does that make sense? If not, can you explain what is confusing you?